# logistic regression for modelling

Tags: r, logistic, modeling

[image]

I have these data plotted above. The explanatory variable represents intensity levels of ground shaking at different locations in an earthquake, and the response variable represents amounts of compensation awarded to damaged buildings. I want to fit a model to these data so that how much compensation is likely to be awarded can be estimated given an intensity level. Can I use logistic regression here? How should I go about building the model for these data? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Logistic regression doesn't apply because your outcome variable isn't categorical. Do you have continuous data on `Intensity`, or only the grouped continuous data in bins of .04? Does the `Intensity` distribution really max out at .48?

Comment: It might be appropriate to [create a sample data set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) (I know it's an SO link but it's sometimes hard to describe quantitative ideas qualitatively!)

Comment: I can see that, but earthquake intensity is continuous, so I'm hoping you have access to continuous data that hasn't been polychotomized/binned like this – it's a waste of information if the original information was more precise. Anyway, I've been trying `rpois(1000,6)*.04+.12` for `Intensity`, but it's not peaked or negatively skewed enough...and [I'm still thinking `Awarded` is gamma-distributed](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/91687/32036), but you have some other good possibilities to consider there.

Comment: Nick - I like the use of the word polychotomized.

Answer (score 2):

Since your response variable (dependent variable) - compensation - is continuous, you wouldn't use logistic regression for this. Logistic regression is normally used to model the underlying probabilities in binomial proportions.

The fact that your predictor (independent variable) has been categorized has no impact on this choice, which is driven by the response variable.

A typical model for data like these might be a GLM. Note that both the mean and the variation change as the predictor changes; the fact that the spread seems to roughly increase with the mean would suggest trying a gamma GLM as a first attempt.

However, the response isn't linear in intensity; you might try a small-order polynomial (such as a quadratic in the log-mean), or you might try splines or some other form of smooth model.

If you have more than a few zeros in the response, you might use a zero-inflated model - essentially to model the probability of any compensation in terms of intensity, and then model the amount of compensation conditional on there being a non-zero amount. (If there are only a few zeros you might simply add a small constant to those few values to allow the gamma fit)

Answer (score 0):

I think quantile regression is the way to go here. First, it makes no assumptions about the distribution of residuals. Second, it allows you to model any quantile of the dependent variable.